# HP Elitebook 2170p - partitions safe to delete?

Tags: partitioning, hp-elitebook

I want to install Windows 8 on my HP EliteBook 2170p.

The problem is that there are, all in all, 4 partitions on the computer, which seems to me prertty useless.
When I try to fromate the partitions though, it says that it MAY be unsafe to do this, as "important files or applications of the computer manufacturer" may get lost.

The four partitions:

- SYSTEM
- C
- HP_RECOVERY
- HP_TOOLS

I'd like very much to have just one partition. However, I'm not sure which of these (if any) are safe to delete and won't do any damage if they don't exist anymore ...

Help's much appreciated!

Comment: related: http://superuser.com/questions/297250/i-have-possibly-extraneous-partitions-can-i-delete-them?rq=1

Comment: Are you intending to **replace** windows 7 or **dual boot**?  I assume replace with the "one partition".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- System (Required if you maintain Win7)

  This is just a 100mb partition Windows puts at the front of their installs (in 7 at least), which contains stuff like bitlocker (if in use) and some boot pieces and recovery piece (enough to get system restore to function, anyway).
- C (Required if you maintain Win7)

  Obviously this is your Install, meaning it is the operating system of Windows 7 (currently) and then your user files (C:\Users[username])
- HP_RECOVERY (optional, could be backed up to DVDs)

  This would be the equivalent of recovery CDs that use to ship with computers, so if W7 dies (or you dislike W8), you could theoretically restore from this.
- HP_TOOLS (Optional, probably backup-able)

  Generally these are their diagnostic tools, so if you call the service center to say my computer is acting funny, they will encourage you to boot into that and run diagnostics to see if any parts are deemed "bad" before they have you ship it in.

In short, which are safe to delete:  That is really up to you.  How badly do you want the ability to restore and run Diagnostics?  Did you back up your User data?  If it is no, yes (respectively) and you no longer want W7 installed - you could delete them all.  However, if you want to keep 7 installed, **do not** delete the System Reserved partition.

Unfortunately, Windows (maybe 8 has changed this..?) can only function on "Primary Partitions", so you will have to remove something if your intention is to dual-boot.

One option for you (if you have the space on an external hard drive) is to backup the disc as an image (with [Norton Ghost](http://us.norton.com/ghost/), [Acronis True Image](http://www.acronis.com/homecomputing/products/trueimage/), or DD on a linux live disc -- I am sure there are free options in Windows, but I am unaware of them right now).

Or, just back up the Recovery stuff to DVD's per [HP's guide](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&docname=c01867124).

**If you are going 100% Windows 8**

I would do the following:

- Backup the Recovery partition to DVD's per the HP's Guide (link above).
- Boot a Linux Live Disc and make a bit-for-bit copy of the tools
  `dd if=/mount/externalHD/HP_Tools.iso of=/dev/sda4` **(Please research DD before performing this)**
- Backup your user data (however you prefer)
- Trash all partitions and start fresh.

Comment: thank your very much. I'm gonna go with deleting all partitions. I hope it'll work!

Comment: @Marco7757  Shouldn't be a problem, just be sure you have your user data backed up :D  #1 is only required if #2 exists, #3/4 are (in my opinion) useless as there are better resources in the opensource world for diagnostics, and I hate factory images b/c of bloat.

Comment: worked like a charm, thank you very much!

I hate manufacturer programs too. When I bought my HP it was all messed by countless HP services, one more useless than the other ...

Finally got rid of them with the update to Windows 8 :D

Comment: @Marco7757 - Great to hear, at some point I intend to try W8 as well.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

HP always have the system recovery stuff in a partition. There is a function key you can press at startup (depends on PC) that will launch a recovery. If you ever get into a state where you just want to start over, this partition can be used to return the computer back to factory settings. Ultimately, it's up to you whether you want to keep it or not. There is nothing to stop to removing all the extra partitions and doing your own thing.